# How can I download a particular update of the JDK from the oracle website?

Tags: java, java-8

I need to use a particular version of the oracle's JDK: 1.8.0_45.

However, I've been clicking around their website for far too long and just can't seem to find it.

I can find a download page for the [most recent release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (8u60 or whatever) and I can find the release notes for [the release I need to use](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u45-relnotes-2494160.html) but I just can't find a link for the 1.8.0_45 release.

Do Oracle not host their old JDKs? Where can I download them that is reliable and secure?

Comment: why do you need to use that specific version? There's rarely a need to use a specific build number older than the current one. If there is, there's almost certainly an installer available inside your organisation already.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for the [Java Archive Downloads - Java SE 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html). For other vesions you can browse through the rest of the [Java Archive](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/oracle-java-archive-downloads.html).

Comment: The more generic answer (not particular to an exact JDK version) to this question is: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/oracle-java-archive-downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Oracle archive. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

In the past you had to login with Oracle credentials. But you can register there for free.